# Why I can't put proxy_set_header inside an if clause?

Tags: configuration, nginx, proxy

With this configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        if ($http_cookie ~* "mycookie") {
            proxy_set_header X-Request $request;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }
    }
}
```

I have this error when I reload nginx service:

```
Reloading nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/check_cookie.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This configuration works OK, but it does not do what I want:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Request $request;
        if ($http_cookie ~* "mycookie") {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't put **proxy_set_header** directive inside an if clause?

Comment: Please don't cross-post. http://serverfault.com/questions/506972/nginx-why-i-cant-put-proxy-set-header-inside-an-if-clause

Comment: I opened a chat to discuss about this. We can continue discussion there. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8745/nginx

Answer (score 11):

Inside location try something like this

```
# default header value in a new variable
set $esb "$remote_addr, $host";

# if my custom header exists
if ($http_my_header){
  set $esb "$http_my_header, $remote_addr, $host";
}

proxy_set_header my-header $esb;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike proxy_pass, you cannot put proxy_set_header inside an if block. You can only put it in http/server/location block. So your 2nd config is good.

Reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

> context:  http, server, location

Don't know what the $request variable is. It doesn't appear in nginx variable list: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: "if cookie 'mycookie' is defined, then put the original URL in a header and send the request to another server"

Comment: Then use $request_uri instead of $request

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't solve the problem. Do you know any way to add that header? I also tried add_header directive with no success http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Comment: what's the symptom? Did you not see the X-Request header in the proxied upstream server? add_header is to add header in the response, proxy_set_header is to add header in the request. They are for different purpose.

Comment: with proxy_set_header (outside the if) works great. With add_header it doesn't. But I only want to add the header if the cookie exists

Comment: I found this module that can be useful: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule. But I'm having some troubles to download the code from github. Have you ever used this module?

Comment: Heard of this module.  But never had a chance to use it yet.